# Largest block size in tezos?

Tags: transactions, consensus, protocol

Is there a limit on the block size in tezos?

If so, is it expressed in a maximum number of transactions? Or maximum byte size? Or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Tezos Alpha the Transaction List size is limited:

> Tezos does not download blocks all at once, but rather considers headers and various lists of operations separately. In Tezos.alpha, a maximum size in bytes is applied to the list of transactions MAX_TRANSACTION_LIST_SIZE = 500kB (that’s 5MB every 10 minutes at most).
>
> Other lists of operations (endorsements, denunciations, reveals) are limited in terms of number of operations (though the defensive programming style also puts limits on the size of operations it expects). [1]

About year ago they had a target of 1 minute between blocks and no size limit set so far:

> We're targeting 1 minute between blocks. We haven't set a blocksize yet, but we'll her on the side of caution at first. It's better to raise the blocksize through the amendment mechanism once we are confident in the network's throughput. [2]

**My source:**

[1] https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html

[2] https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/6a803e/tezos_blocksize_blockchain_growth/